An alternative way to solve a classic problem of combinatorics
The problem is to count how many permutations in $S_n$ have no fixed points. Let call this number $f(n)$, and define the set $N=\{1,\ldots,n\}$.
The 'classic' solution is using the exclusion-inclusion principle to get
\begin{align*}n!&=f(n)+\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{A\subseteq N,\#A=k}(-1)^k\#\{\sigma\in S_n: j\in A\to\sigma(j)=j\}\\
&=f(n)+\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\binom nk(n-k)!\\
&=f(n)+n!\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\end{align*}
My alternative try:
I have tried to define recursively the sequence $f(n)$ as follows:
Let $B(A)=\#\{\sigma\in S_n: \sigma(j)=j \leftrightarrow j\in A\}$ for $A\subseteq N$ (note the 'iff' in the definition).
$$f(0)=1$$
\begin{align*} f(n)&=n!-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{A\subseteq N,\#A=k}B(A)\\
&=n!-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom nkf(n-k)\\
&=n!-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom nkf(k)\end{align*}
My question:
I'm struggling if there is a way to get the former result from the latter (that is, to solve the reecursive equation) avoiding the exclusion-inclusion principle, i.e,. by purely 'algebraic' means.
My thoughts:
This suggests that I should prove that
$$n!\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom nkf(k)$$
I have tried induction to no avail so far.
Another alternative way
Since a permutation can be expressed uniquely as a product of disjoint cycles, we can solve the problem for $n=7$ this way:
A permutation with no fixed points can be expressed as a product of disjoint cycles of order $\ge 2$.

If the order of cycles are 2-2-3, there are $\frac{\binom 72\binom 52\binom 33(2-1)!(2-1)!(3-1)!}{2!}=210$ permutations.
If it is 3-4, there are $\binom 73\binom 44(3-1)!(4-1)!=420$.
If it is 2-5, there are $\binom 72\binom 55(2-1)!(5-1)!=504$.
If it is a 7-cycle, there are $(7-1)!=720$.

The sum is $1854$.
But I guess that this is difficult to do for arbitrary $n$.

Your alternative equation can be written
$$
n!=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nkf(k).\tag1
$$
From this, we can derive the exponential generating function for $f$, and hence derive the original formula $f(k)$. Multiplying both sides of $(1)$ by $\frac{x^n}{n!}$, we get
$$
x^n=\frac{x^n}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk f(k)=x^n\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f(k)}{k!}\cdot \frac1{(n-k)!}\tag2
$$
Next, summing both sides of $(2)$ from $n=0$ to $\infty$, we get
$$
\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f(k)}{k!}\cdot \frac1{(n-k)!}\tag3
$$
You can now recognize that the RHS of $(3)$ is the series which is the Cauchy product of the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f(k)}{k!}x^k$ with the series $\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\ell!}x^\ell$. The latter has closed form $e^x$, so we obtain
$$
\frac1{1-x}=e^x\cdot \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f(k)}{k!}x^k.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n f(k)\frac{x^k}{k!}=\frac{e^{-x}}{1-x}.\tag4
$$
You can then recover the original formula for $f(n)$. From $(4)$, we have that
$$
f(n)=n!\cdot [x^n] \Big( e^{-x}\cdot (1-x)^{-1}\Big)
$$
Finally, $[x^n] \Big( e^{-x}\cdot (1-x)^{-1}\Big)$ is given by the convolution of the sequence of coefficients for $e^{-x}$ and the sequence of coefficients for $\frac1{1-x}$.
$$
f(n)=n!\cdot [x^n]\frac{e^{-x}}{1-x}=n![x^n]\left(\sum_i \frac{x^i(-1)^i}{i!}\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty x^j\right)=n!\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}.
$$

You mean $\frac{x^n}{n!}$? I think it would be good to insert one or maybe two additional steps in the algebra there for someone who's never seen this argument before.

As Mike says the key is to rewrite the recursion as
$$n! = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} f(k).$$
In general, suppose you are in a situation where you have two sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ related by the identity
$$a_n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} b_k.$$
This is sometimes called the binomial transform, although there appear to be three slightly different things called this name, two of which insert signs.

Theorem ("binomial inversion"): The above identity is equivalent to the identity
$$b_n = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k} {n \choose k} a_k.$$

This is the "inverse binomial transform" (although again, as a warning, conventions differ on where the signs should be inserted) and the desired identity readily follows.
The theorem can be proven in at least four different ways I can think of, all of which are arguably equivalent. The first is to use inclusion-exclusion. The second is to use Möbius inversion on a poset, namely the poset of subsets of an $n$-element set; this is essentially a more general way to phrase what inclusion-exclusion is doing. The third and fourth proofs use generating functions, and interestingly this is a case where either ordinary or exponential generating functions can be used. Both effectively "do the inclusion-exclusion automatically for you."
Mike's proof generalizes as follows. Write $A(x) = \sum a_n \frac{x^n}{n!}$ and $B(x) = \sum b_n \frac{x^n}{n!}$. Then
$$\begin{align*} A(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} b_k \\
 &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^{n-k}}{(n-k)!} b_k \frac{x^k}{k!} \\
 &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} b_k \frac{x^k}{k!} \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n-k}}{(n-k)!} \\
 &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} b_k \frac{x^k}{k!} e^x \\
 &= e^x B(x). \end{align*}$$
The key step is the third line where we interchange the order of summation. The algebra here can be avoided if you know how exponential generating functions multiply, I just want to be explicit if you're seeing this for the first time. This gives $B(x) = e^{-x} A(x)$, and then you expand this back out again. So the binomial and inverse binomial transform are really simple in terms of exponential generating functions, you just multiply and divide by $e^x$ respectively. This is closely analogous to the proof of Möbius inversion using Dirichlet series, where you just multiply and divide by $\zeta(s)$ respectively.
The fourth proof uses ordinary rather than exponential generating functions and is a little harder. Now write $F(x) = \sum a_n x^n, G(x) = \sum b_n x^n$ (no factorials). Then
$$\begin{align*} F(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} b_k x^n \\
 &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} b_k x^k \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} {n \choose k} x^{n-k} \\
 &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} b_k \frac{x^k}{(1 - x)^{k+1}} \\
 &= \frac{1}{1 - x} G \left( \frac{x}{1 - x} \right) \end{align*}$$
where on the second line we interchange the order of summation and on the third line we need a generating function identity for $\frac{1}{(1 - x)^{k+1}}$; see stars and bars. This can be inverted to express $G$ in terms of $F$ by substituting $y = \frac{x}{1 - x}$, which gives $x = \frac{y}{1 + y}$, so
$$G(y) = \frac{1}{1 + y} F \left( \frac{y}{1 + y} \right).$$
Then this can be expanded back out. In this case the exponential generating functions are clearly nicer but sometimes in other situations the ordinary generating functions are nicer.
